# Unity Unexpected Sound Behavior

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Im taking a Unity C# course on Udemy, and we got to an challenge and i came up with a very simple "game". My problem is i can't figure out why no sound is playing? I looked at the instructors code and is the same as my (or did i just miss something?)

When i press on space the rocket starts flying (this works) and should play sound (it doesnt). Yes i got a SoundListener attached to the main camera.
Can somebody help and explain me where i missed something?

[image: Image of my game (if you cant call it so)]

Here is my code that i wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rocket : MonoBehaviour
{

    Rigidbody rigidBody;
    AudioSource audioSource;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ProcessInput();
    }

    private void ProcessInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) // can thrust while rotating
        {
            rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up);
            if (!audioSource.isPlaying) // so it doesn't layer
            {
                audioSource.Play();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            audioSource.Stop();
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.Rotate(-Vector3.forward);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it after after declaring the audioSource to public